# How to get a value in ng-repeat without ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

I am using `ng-repeat` for iterating a list of objects. When the user selects an option, I want that object, not a single value. `ng-model` only seems to give me the id.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/1416/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I tried to fix up the English and syntax as best I could, I hope I did your question justice, while making it easier to understand for other users who might be able to help you. Please consider adding the code you're having trouble with, as that will go a long way in allowing others to understand your issue. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your select to use the object, and thus the model:

```
<select
  ng-model="vm.subapp"
  ng-options="subapp.name for subapp in vm.subapplicationList">
</select>
```

It'll show the name, but it'll use the object. So for you, vm.subapps (or this.subapps in your controller) is an object.

Edit: since you don't want to show the Id you can simply change your alert line:

```
alert(JSON.stringify($scope.subappData.value));
```

Then you won't be showing the ID. Also, don't think you need the JSON.stringify(), but also suggest using console.log() instead of alert()

Comment: i dont want to use ng-model because it will show id value

Comment: If your aim is to display the 'description' of the selected item, use alert(JSON.stringify($scope.subappData.DESCRIPCION));

Comment: i want to get value as alert data but by using alert(JSON.stringify($scope.subappData.DESCRIPCION));  i am not getting value as alert

Comment: Then alert out $scope.subappData.value

Answer (score 0):

You should hold the id and value in an object:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <select class="form-control selectpicker"  data-live-search="true"   ng-model="subappData"  id="subapplicationid" style="height: 21px;width: 300px;-moz-margin-start: 132px;margin-left: 138px;margin-top: 2px;-moz-margun-start: 132px;">
         <option value="">Select</option>
      <option  ng-repeat='subapp in subapplicationList | filter:query' data-select-watcher data-last="{{$last}}" value = "{{subapp.ID}}"> <a href="#"> {{subapp.ID}} - {{subapp.DESCRIPCION}} </a> </option>
               </select>
    <div>                   
   <div>
    <button  ng-click="whenClick()">Click</button>
   </div>     
    </div>  
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.subapplicationList = [
  {"ID" :  9 ,"DESCRIPCION" : "a","value" : 24 },
  {"ID" :  1 ,"DESCRIPCION" : "b","value" : 7 },
  {"ID" :  2 ,"DESCRIPCION" : "c","value" : 12 },
  {"ID" :  3 ,"DESCRIPCION" : "d","value" : 2 },
  ];
   $scope.whenClick = function() {
   alert(JSON.stringify($scope.subappData));
  };
});
myapp.directive('selectWatcher', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var last = attr.last;
            if (last === "true") {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $(element).parent().selectpicker('val', 1);
                    $(element).parent().selectpicker('refresh');

                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Working code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0qaas75w/)